# Cut 10 seconds from the beginning of a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I remove `X` seconds from the beginning of a video using `ffmpeg`?

What I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10
ffmpeg -ss 10

ffmpeg -ss "11" -i season.avi -vf "movie=/storage/conv_sctipt/watermark.mov  [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10, fade=in:0:20 [out]" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -y -acodec libfaac -ab 64K -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -b 555K -bt 666k -threads 0  "season.flv"
```

Then I get the following errors, and `ffmpeg` continues:

```
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.00 bitrate= 477.6kbits/s    
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d31380] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d1f180] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d17e40] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.78 bitrate= 582.2kbits/s    
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d34d80] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d38780] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.30 bitrate= 626.1kbits/s    
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d17a00] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.48 bitrate= 672.6kbits/s    
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.99 bitrate= 649.6kbits/s    
[mpeg4 @ 0x3d22b80] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.33 bitrate= 610.6kbits/s    
Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected.80 bitrate= 628.9kbits/s
```

Comment: Please include your actual ffmpeg command and the complete, uncut ffmpeg console output.

Comment: found the solution here http://superuser.com/questions/149010/how-do-you-splice-out-a-part-of-an-xvid-encoded-avi-file-with-ffmpeg-no-probl